# How to use sed's substitute with a regex pattern as variable?

Tags: command-line, regex, cygwin, sed

Let us say that we have the following as stdin (as an example)

```
Life is temporary
```

I want sed to replace this with

```
Life is permanent
```

with a command somewhere along the lines of

`sed 's/Life<%XY=.*>temporary/Life%XYpermanent'`

Of course, I know that the above is not a valid command, it is to serve as an example. I want to store whatever that `.*` matches into a variable, and I want to recall that variable in the replace string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/Life\(.*\)temporary/Life\1permanent/'
```

Here `\1` refers to the first pair of parentheses in the pattern. It's the only pair in this case, but in general you can have more pairs and then you can use `\2`, `\3` etc., up to `\9`.

The parentheses are escaped. Without `\` they would be taken literally and `\1` wouldn't work. If you use `sed -E` then it will be reversed: `(` will be special and `\(` will denote a literal `(` (note in general it's not the only difference `-E` makes):

```
sed -E 's/Life(.*)temporary/Life\1permanent/'
```

This change makes our `sed` code somewhat more readable for humans.